# I want to disable or hide one or two textboxes based on a dropdownlist selection from my view page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to basically disable or hide an editable textbox based on a selection from my dropdown list. I have a Delivery view page with statuses that I have hard-coded onto the model, and I also have separate textboxes that allow me to select the date and time for each status. All of which are currently displayed on the form.

Based on the status which could either be "Dispatched", "Received", "Delayed", I want to disable or hide (whichever option is practical) the corresponding date and time textbox of the other statuses. So for example, if I select 'Dispatched', I want to disable or hide the `delayed_date` and `delayed_time` as well as `received_date` and `received_time` textboxes. This is so the user can focus on the textbox related to the status they have selected.

How would I go about doing the above? I have done a bit of research on this but I have no idea how to apply it to my situation. I'm fairly new to MVC so I'm looking for a simple easy-to understand method of doing this. Is there an alternative to using jQuery or Javascript? Thanks in advance!

Delivery Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace HealthHabitat.Models
{
    public enum Status
    {
        Delivered, Delayed, Dispatched
    }
    public class Delivery
    {

        public int DeliveryID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Driver")]
        public string DriverID { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Dispatched")]
        public DateTime Dispatched_Date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Time Dispatched")]
        public DateTime Dispatched_Time { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Received")]
        public DateTime? Received_Date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Time Received")]
        public DateTime? Received_Time { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Delayed")]
        public DateTime? Delayed_Date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Time Delayed")]
        public DateTime? Delayed_Time { get; set; }



        public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Create Delivery View:

```
@model HealthHabitat.Models.Delivery

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}



@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Delivery</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DriverID, "DriverID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("DriverID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DriverID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dispatched_Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dispatched_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dispatched_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dispatched_Time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dispatched_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dispatched_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Received_Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Received_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Received_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Received_Time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Received_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Received_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Delayed_Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Delayed_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Delayed_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Delayed_Time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Delayed_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Delayed_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

                <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    <a href="~/Delivery/Index" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: I've tried to add jQuery scripts from other examples but I don't think I applied it correctly because it didn't work. I've tried using if statements - that didn't work either. I know how to disable and hide the textbox in general, but I want it to do that based on my dropdown list selection. So I'm stumped.

Comment: You can give each group of elements a data-attribibute, then the onchange event of dropdown, pass a value to a method u create, this method can hide only the elements you want, you can use a switch statement to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since (I presume) the dropdown can be changed without posting the form, a JavaScript solution will be best here. jQuery should make this pretty easy:

First, as @mahlatse suggested, add a `data-attribute` to all of the `form-group` divs that matches the enum values. Also, add some custom class name that you pick, like `section`:

```
<div class="form-group section" data-attribute="1">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dispatched_Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dispatched_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dispatched_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group section" data-attribute="1">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dispatched_Time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dispatched_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dispatched_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

... and so on. This will ensure we can accurately show and hide each group of divs easily. The `section` class will ensure we can refer to all of these divs as a group later, too. Next, find the HTML ID of the dropdown list (or assign one to it), and hook up a jQuery event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown-id-here').change(function(data) {
        var selected = data.target.value;
        switchUi(selected);
    });
)};
```

[.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) is jQuery's way of attaching code to the control's change event. The CSS selector `#dropdown-id-here` is how it knows which control to attach the code to. `data.target.value` is the string `value` of the selected dropdown option.

Next, a helper function:

```
function switchUi(selection) {
    $('div.section').filter('[data-attribute="' + selection + '"]').show();
    $('div.section').not('[data-attribute="' + selection + '"]').hide();
}
```

The first line selects all divs on the page with the `section` class and then finds only the ones that have `data-attribute=<selected option value>`. [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) ensures those divs are visible. The second line just inverts this logic and hides **all** divs that do not have the currently selected option as their `data-attribute`.

We also want it to fire this off on page load, so whatever initial selection the dropdown has is reflected on the page immediately. Add another line to `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...

    switchUi($('#dropdown-id-here').val());
});
```

Here's a simple fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/9f6nqcvt/3/

---

Some further thoughts:

- You'll need to control what value MVC assigns to the dropdown control's HTML `id`.
- Make sure you aren't **completely** relying on the textboxes being hidden; include some simple server-side validation that ensures the user doesn't enter bad data.

Comment: Hi Nate, thank you so much for your detailed response, this really makes it easier to understand. I just have one question with regards to the jQuery. Do I add this code to the bottom of the specific view page under '@Scripts render' or do I make a script file and then add it there? Does it make a difference which way I do it?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if it's included inline in the page, or in an external file that's referenced. Either way, though, you'll probably need to place or reference the script near the bottom of the page so that it will be executed last, after the page loads. Let me know if you have any problems with it.

Comment: It runs but my entire page is being hidden instead of just the corresponding textboxes. Could it possibly be that `$('div')` is picking up the `div class="form-horizontal">` at the beginning of my form?

Comment: Oops, my bad. You're absolutely right, the code was a little too greedy. This can be fixed by adding an additional class like `section` (or whatever you want) to the divs, so we can use the selector `$('div.section')...` to only act on those. I updated the example and fiddle above. I also made one other change: adding the `.change()` wireup code to the `document.ready` block, so it doesn't matter if  you put the script at the beginning or end; it will run when the page has finished loading, as we want.

Comment: It shows the form now, but it doesn't show the respective textbox with regards to the status. It just shows the status textbox and the driver textbox.

Comment: @K.Naidoo Does switching the dropdown cause anything to appear? Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I don't want to clutter these comments up too much -- let's move this to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88022/so-32169731).

Comment: Updated to use numerical (enum) values as the `data-attribute` instead of string values, per our discussion. Cheers!